# Where to ask "Can I build a simple dredge using a venturi pump type apparatus?"

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I am building what I hope will be a simple dredge to clean silt and leaves (12 inches of silt and leaves and water) in the bottom of an almost drained pool. I am using parts from the hardware store and a Venturi nozzle.

```
 ---------------
 A>  B>  C>
 ----   --------
    /  /
   /  /
    ^
    |
 SUCTION IN
```

The high pressure water is injected from the left and refuse ejected at right, with refuse pulled in from bottom. My question: What is the optimal placement for the tip of the high pressure water jet nozzle inside the Y. Should it be A) before the suction pipe entry, B) in the middle of the entry, or C) just past the entry, to produce the greatest suction. The nozzle goes from 1 inch to 1/4 inch in diameter. After testing the prototype I found that C) does the best. Not sure if a D) an inch into the exhaust pipe would be better.

Does this even make sense or am I completely missing the point on how this works?

I know I cannot ask this on the Physics Stack Exchange site.

Comment: You may try asking this at the general [Engineering](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/) site.

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest one of:

- [DIY (Home Improvement)](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour)
- [Gardening](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/tour)